# Access user profile information using gmail api by just email address

Tags: python, google-api, google-plus, gmail-api

I am using Gmail API V1. I want to get full name & profile picture of the sender by using an email address. 
[Users: getProfile](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/getProfile) this API just returns email address, history etc. It doesn't provide total profile information.

I checked google plus API also ([people.get](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get)). It returns profile info but by using user id, not by email address.

Can we get user profile info by email address?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Google does not offer an endpoint to do an unauthenticated search on a user by email address.

If you have access to run a gmail users then you should ask the user for profile scope as well.  then you can do

> GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me

The response will contain a link to the image of the user.

If you are looking for pictures of random users then this is not something you can do.

Comment: Ok Thanks for reply. I am using this end point to get user profile of login user. But I wanted profile info of random user by email address.

Comment: as I said in the last line.  There is no way to get a random users Google profile picture with their email

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much for reply. Cann't we get full name also?

Comment: you can only get information about a user who has authenticated your application.  There is no way to search for random Google users this is private information.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo then how can my gmail inbox is able to show me the profile picture of a email address whenever I enter the address in `to`?

Comment: Because Google owns this information,  and has access to everyone's data.